# Sort Array of NSString By Custom Method

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

How would I go about sorting an array of NSString Objects by a custom method. For example I have a method

```
-(int)calculateValue:(NSString *)aString
```

I would like to sort an array by descending order based on the returned value from this method. So for example I have an array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Bee", @"Super", nil];
```

Now if I call calculateValue for each of those strings it might return values such as.

"Apple" = 15, "Bee" = 21, and "Super" = 3. Now I'm trying to sort that array based on the returned value for each NSString from the calculateValue method. So then the sorted array would like like

```
[Bee, Apple, Super]
```

Comment: What do you mean "based on the returned value"? What does this method do/return?

Comment: the calculateValue just returns an int value based on the string. So apple might return 15 while able might return 13. So if a sort were performed apple would come before able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [-sortedArrayUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a). You'll pass in a selector like `@selector(myComparisonMethod:)`. Your comparison method should return an NSComparisonResult like NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending, or NSOrderedSame.

Comment: Note that this assumes the comparison method is a method *of the objects in the array*. The question doesn't specify, so I figure it's worth pointing out.

Comment: - (NSComparisonResult)comparePointValue:(NSString *)otherString {
 
 int thisString = [calculateValue:self];
 int other = [calculateValue:otherString];
 
 if (thisString > other) {
  return NSOrderedDescending;
 }
 else if (thisString < other) {
 
  return NSOrderedAscending;
 }
 return NSOrderedSame;
}

Comment: @Chuck: A very good point. I should've mentioned this should be an Objective-C category on NSString.

Comment: @aahrens: I think you've got it. The only thing is I usually get confused as to which direction (asc/desc) to return and am too lazy to look it up at the moment. :-) Just make sure you read the docs to make sure you're not swapping the order around from the expected.